# Is there a way to import a JSON file in Laravel to create a form based on that specific file?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have been facing with this issue where I have to create forms from a JSON file.

I am supposed to create a JSON file which will consists of classes, input element types, their names which will be responsible for creating a blade template for me

It will output the content in one specific format or you can say that it will work as a boiler plate for the crud operations required.

My output will look very much like [this](https://codepen.io/runtimeterror97/pen/qBjqeWw)

My JSON file is like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "layout-name": "blog-create",
      "title": "Blog",
      "links": [
        {
          "add": "localhost:8000/blog/create",
          "edit": "localhost:8000/blog/edit/{id}",
          "update": "localhost:8000/blog/update/{id}",
          "delete": "localhost:8000/blog/delete/{id}",
          "show": "localhost:8000/blog/show/{id}",
          "index": "localhost:8000/blog"
        }
      ],
      "form": {
        "title": "Blog Create",
        "id": "blog-form",
        "method": "post",
        "action": "localhost:8000/blog/create",
        "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "_token",
            "type": "text",
            "value": "csrf_token()"
          },
          {
            "name": "title",
            "placeholder": "Please enter a post tile",
            "class": [
              "form-control",
              "col-md-12",
              "col-lg-6"
            ],
            "id": "title",
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Post Title"
          },
          {
            "name": "image",
            "placeholder": "Please select an image",
            "class": [
              "form-control",
              "col-md-12",
              "col-lg-6"
            ],
            "id": "image",
            "type": "file",
            "label": "Post Image"
          },
          {
            "name": "post",
            "placeholder": "Please enter a post body",
            "class": [
              "ckeditor",
              "col-md-12",
              "col-lg-6"
            ],
            "id": "post",
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Post Body"
          },
          {
            "name": "submit",
            "class": [
              "btn",
              "btn-primary"
            ],
            "id": "submit",
            "type": "text",
            "value": "Submit"
          },
          {
            "name": "reset",
            "class": [
              "btn",
              "btn-warning"
            ],
            "id": "reset",
            "type": "reset"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I think you will now be able to grasp what I want to achieve in this task.

Now lets come to the main question, **Is this even achievable in Laravel? If yes, how? I have no idea how to render this type of content**

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I am also attaching my HTML markup. I don't want to add any header or sections as they are already being rendered by my previously written code, I just want to render a plain HTML markup without any script, I have just added the script in this case to visualize the output!

What I will be able to achieve with this task? I have to repeatedly create CRUD operation files at my work following this specific format so I will be able to minimize the required time to complete tasks instead of looking for a closing tag I forgot to copy while referencing it from some other template!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/29.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body class="mt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card col-6 offset-lg-3">
      <form action="localhost:8000/blog/store" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="lead">
            <h4>Blog create</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="{{csrf_token()}}">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Post Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-sm-12" id="title" placeholder="Please enter a post tile" id="title">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Post Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-sm-12" id="image" placeholder="Please select a file" id="image">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Post Body</label>
                <input type="text" class="ckeditor col-lg-12 col-sm-12" id="post" name="post" placeholder="Please enter a post tile">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-warning">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    ClassicEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('.ckeditor'))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/laravel-shift/blueprint but I don't think it does everything but views.
A couple of days ago I started making the same thing that you want, make crud views from from artisan since nothing good exists.
I just created stubs and replaced the variables. Made a file for each field type and one for each method. I still have work to do, trying to find the better code for the stubs. Then I want to make it create model's and controller's as well.

Comment: I really only need views, for alot of code is repeated in that part for me! I just want to simply to create a basic layout for work, just a work around for all the repetitive stuff